# Build PJSIP in QT

Tags: c++, pjsip, qt5.2

I want to write a C++ application which works with PJSIP in order to create sip calls to IP phone.
after added libraries and remove errors .I had runtimes errors about libraries that I attached the own QT.
now I am facing with this problem.

`:-1: error: dependent 'C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\CppSip\C:\Program' does not exist.`

after added MSVCPRT.lib this error appeared.